# Recurrence relation for calculating a number using power & base

Tags: recurrence

```
function exp2(base , power) 
 if (power = 0) 
 return 1 
 else if (power = 1) 
 return base 
 else if (mod(power, 2) = 0) 
 tmp  exp2(base, power/2) 
 return tmp  tmp 
 else 
 return base  exp2(base,power-1)
```

what is the reccurce relation of this code? How should  I refer to the "if", "else"  conditions while creating my equation?